# Inno Setup - Uninstall Registry Removal Option

Tags: inno-setup

The program I'm building an installer for uses registry entries to store user settings. Right now I have it set to delete said registry files when the program is uninstalled, but I would like the ability to give users an option to either keep or delete the registry files upon uninstall.

I'm not the best scripter/programmer, so the simpler the answer, the better.

My registry/uninstall currently looks like this.

```
    [Registry]
    Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\FFSPLIT Overlay Filter"; Flags: uninsdeletekey


    [UninstallDelete]  
    Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}\ffmpeg"
    Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}\OverlayData"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\AForge.Controls.dll"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\AForge.Imaging.dll"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\AForge.Video.DirectShow.dll"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\AForge.Video.dll"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\AudioFilter.ax"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\default.cfg"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\DirectShowLib-2005.dll"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\ffmpeg.exe"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\FFSplit Overlay Filter.ax"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\FFsplit.exe"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\FFSplitOverlayManager.exe"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\librtmp.dll"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\msvcp100d.dll"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\msvcr100d.dll"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\NAudio.dll"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\RegisterFilter.bat"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\setting.cfg"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\UNRegisterFilter.bat"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\wavbuffer"
    Type: files; Name: "{app}\Micfilter.ax"
```

Comment: Note that you don't need `[UninstallDelete]` entries for anything that's installed by a `[Files]` entry -- they're uninstalled by default anyway.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

InnoSetup doesn't have any conditional uninstall check parameter, so you have to do this by yourself. So you need to remove the `uninsdeletekey` flag which would delete the registry key automatically and at the end of the uninstallation process you can ask user if he wants to delete that key (in some meaningful message way) and delete the key manually. The following script does this at the post uninstall step, what is the time when the application was successfully uninstalled. You can follow the [`commented version`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12645836/1):

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

#define FilterRegKey "Software\FFSPLIT Overlay Filter"

[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "{#FilterRegKey}"

[Code]
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall then
  begin
    if RegKeyExists(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, '{#FilterRegKey}') then
      if MsgBox('Do you want to delete the overlay filter registry key ?',
        mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES
      then
        RegDeleteKeyIncludingSubkeys(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, '{#FilterRegKey}');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate it. Saved me quite a deal of headache and I'll be sure to refer to this from now on.

Comment: Note that this will at most remove the key from one user.  If the app is installed per-machine and multiple users run it, the settings will remain for all but the one who happens to run the uninstaller.  If that bothers you, there is no solution for this except making your install per-user instead (`PrivilegesRequired=lowest`), which in turn comes with restrictions on where you can install to and which flags you can use.