# How to add a confirm task during uninstall section by using inno setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I have a user data located at user's folder such as : C:\Users\Administrator\profile.ini

I know how to delete it:

```
[UninstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "C:\Users\{username}\profile.ini"
```

The thing is i don't want to delete this file silently, i need the end-user informed about this operation with a checkbox, like "[ ] Delete user data".
If end-user checks it, delete this file, otherwise do nothing.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to get the current logging user's folder? I don't think it's a good way like what i did above "C:\Users{username}\". But i couldn't find any constant for doing this.
2. Is it possible to add a checkbox at the beginning of uninstallation?

Comment: 1) don't you rather want to store that `profile.ini` file into the [`user's Application Data`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#userappdata) folder ? 2) where do you want to add that check box ? There's just a confirmation dialog at the beginning of the uninstaller with which user can interact as far as I know...

Comment: As TLama said, you're using the wrong folder.  But also, there is no reliable way (in Windows in general, not Inno specifically) to delete user data on uninstall.  It's usually not worth even trying.

Comment: What a way to pick a name that's likely to conflict with anything... profile.ini in the root of the user's profile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstall Registry Removal Option](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12644913/588306)

Comment: Thanks, problem solve by using some code while uninstalling. But as you said, really not worth even trying, just want to learning some principles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uninstaller does not support making changes to the wizard UI.

You can however use normal `[Code]` to prompt the user with a custom form or message box. See [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12645836/588306) for a sample.