# inno setup ask user if to Uninstall Files

Tags: installation, inno-setup

During the install , I add folder with files:
Source: {#DBPath};  DestDir: "{app}\DataBase";
I want that in the Uninstall, inno-setup will ask the user if 
To delete the files or not.

How can I do that ?
Thanks, Avi.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a confirm task during uninstall section by using inno setup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503260/how-to-add-a-confirm-task-during-uninstall-section-by-using-inno-setup)

Answer (score 6):

If u want to keep a folder then u should add `uninsneveruninstall` flag to instruct inno-setup not to
delete this folder during uninstallation.Then you can conditionally remove this folder with Pascal script

Here is how to do this :

```
[Files]
Source: {#DBPath}; DestDir: {app}\DataBase; Flags: uninsneveruninstall

[Code]
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall then
  begin
    if MsgBox('Do You Want To Delete DataBase Folder?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO or MB_DEFBUTTON2) = IDYES then
    //this is the msg that will display after uninstall,change is as you prefer 
    begin
        DelTree(ExpandConstant('{app}\DataBase'), True, True, True);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Just found this. After hours of searching, it was just what I needed.