# Need an equivalent to sharedfile for start-menu shortcut in inno

Tags: inno-setup

I have 2 installers for 2 different applications, both of which also install a common support/diagnostic tool.

For the exe file I have added the sharedfile flag, so that when a user installs both applications and then uninstalls one of them, the diagnostic tool remains.

However, I also add a start-menu shortcut to the diagnostic tool, which gets deleted by the uninstaller.

How can I make the shortcut remain if one of the applications still exists, or if the diagnostic tool exe is still there, but delete if both applications are removed (or only one was installed in the first place)?

```
[files]
Source: "{app}_dynamic\SupportApp\*.*"; DestDir: "{app}\SupportApp"; Flags: sharedfile; Components: Support

[icons]
Name: "{group}\Tools\Send diagnostic logs"; Filename: "{app}\SupportApp\Support.exe"; Flags: uninsneveruninstall; Components: Support
```

[edit] 
Came up with this:

(initial work done by TLama: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12645836/2021217)

```
[code]
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
    if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall then
    begin
        if (not(FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\SupportApp\Support.exe'))) then
        begin
            if (MsgBox('deleting "' + ExpandConstant('{group}') + '\Tools". "' + ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\SupportApp\Support.exe" doesnt exist', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES) then
            begin
                DeleteFile('"' + ExpandConstant('{group}') + '\Tools\Send diagnostic logs"');

                DeleteFile('"' + ExpandConstant('{group}') + '\Tools\Send diagnostic logs.lnk"');

                RemoveDir('"' + ExpandConstant('{group}') + '\Tools"');
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

It all seems to work, except for the deletion part...the deletefile and removedir function calls don't seem to work!
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Yes, that might be the way. Just remove all the `"` quotes from the parameters to make those function work.

Comment: I added the quotes to the functions in an attempt to make them work, it wasn't working without them either unfortunately?

Comment: If you get the proper `{group}` path, then it should work. Of course without those quotes... Besides, you're removing the whole `{group}\Tools` directory, so it's easier to delete the whole directory with all the files inside by calling `DelTree(ExpandConstant('{group}\Tools'), True, True, True)`. Just one thing to note; you must ensure that both applications you install will have the same group...

Comment: I didn't know about DelTree, or that I could include the 'Tools' in the expandconstant(). I added those in as you said and it is now deleting them correctly...thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! You've come up with the solution and you can post answer to your own questions, so feel free to do so. You can get some rep for that ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[code]
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
    if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall then
    begin
        if (not(FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\SupportApp\Support.exe')))) then
            DelTree(ExpandConstant('{group}\Tools'), True, True, True);
    end;
end;
```

Many Thanks to TLama for guiding me to a final solution.